# SQl server - lookup rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Guys need help in sql server.
I have a table with Country names in it, for example I have data for Country " Korea" like
Korea
South Korea
Korea South East
Korea South West
Central Korea
Now I would need only "Korea" for all of the above country. These countries refers to single one, when cube is browsed, sales are shattered across all these countries, in DSV I am using named query and hence thinking to get achieve something in SQL query. Can this be done? any work around will be helpful.

Comment: It's quite hard to help you with the question presented as it is. Please share your tables' structures, some sample data and the result you're trying to get for that sample.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a mapping table or query like below

```
select 
case when country in 
(
'Korea'
'South Korea'
 'Korea South East'
 'Korea South West'
 'Central Korea'
 ) then 'Korea' else country end 
 as country, sum(amount) as amount
 from table
 group by
case when country in 
(
'Korea'
'South Korea'
 'Korea South East'
 'Korea South West'
 'Central Korea'
 ) then 'Korea' else country end
```

Comment: Thank you, But I cannot hard code any values as I have around 260 distinct values. Mapping table would be my worst case scenario, I am trying for best cases if at all available.